# TensorFlow: Max of a tensor along an axis

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, max, tensor

My question is in two connected parts:

1. How do I calculate the max along a certain axis of a tensor? For example, if I have

   ```
   x = tf.constant([[1,220,55],[4,3,-1]])
   ```

   I want something like

   ```
   x_max = tf.max(x, axis=1)
   print sess.run(x_max)

   output: [220,4]
   ```

   I know there is a `tf.argmax` and a `tf.maximum`, but neither give the maximum value along an axis of a single tensor. For now I have a workaround:

   ```
   x_max = tf.slice(x, begin=[0,0], size=[-1,1])
   for a in range(1,2):
       x_max = tf.maximum(x_max , tf.slice(x, begin=[0,a], size=[-1,1]))
   ```

   But it looks less than optimal. Is there a better way to do this?
2. Given the indices of an `argmax` of a tensor, how do I index into another tensor using those indices? Using the example of `x` above, how do I do something like the following:

   ```
   ind_max = tf.argmax(x, dimension=1)    #output is [1,0]
   y = tf.constant([[1,2,3], [6,5,4])
   y_ = y[:, ind_max]                     #y_ should be [2,6]
   ```

   I know slicing, like the last line, does not exist in TensorFlow yet ([#206](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/206)).

   My question is: *what is the best workaround for my specific case (maybe using other methods like gather, select, etc.)?*

   Additional information: I know `x` and `y` are going to be two dimensional tensors only!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The [`tf.reduce_max()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#reduce_max) operator provides exactly this functionality. By default it computes the global maximum of the given tensor, but you can specify a list of `reduction_indices`, which has the same meaning as `axis` in NumPy. To complete your example:

```
x = tf.constant([[1, 220, 55], [4, 3, -1]])
x_max = tf.reduce_max(x, reduction_indices=[1])
print sess.run(x_max)  # ==> "array([220,   4], dtype=int32)"
```

If you compute the argmax using [`tf.argmax()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#argmax), you could obtain the the values from a different tensor `y` by flattening `y` using [`tf.reshape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#reshape), converting the argmax indices into vector indices as follows, and using [`tf.gather()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#gather) to extract the appropriate values:

```
ind_max = tf.argmax(x, dimension=1)
y = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [6, 5, 4]])

flat_y = tf.reshape(y, [-1])  # Reshape to a vector.

# N.B. Handles 2-D case only.
flat_ind_max = ind_max + tf.cast(tf.range(tf.shape(y)[0]) * tf.shape(y)[1], tf.int64)

y_ = tf.gather(flat_y, flat_ind_max)

print sess.run(y_) # ==> "array([2, 6], dtype=int32)"
```

Comment: For completeness, in your second example, please add on the 3rd line: `amax = tf.argmax(y, 1)` and remove the first line.

Comment: `reduction_indices` is deprecated. use `axis` instead

Answer (score 3):

As of **TensorFlow 1.10.0**-*dev20180626*, [**`tf.reduce_max`**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_max) accepts `axis` and `keepdims` keyword arguments offering the similar functionality of `numpy.max`.

```
In [55]: x = tf.constant([[1,220,55],[4,3,-1]])

In [56]: tf.reduce_max(x, axis=1).eval() 
Out[56]: array([220,   4], dtype=int32)
```

To have a resultant tensor of the same dimension as the input tensor, use `keepdims=True`

```
In [57]: tf.reduce_max(x, axis=1, keepdims=True).eval()Out[57]: 
array([[220],
       [  4]], dtype=int32)
```

---

If the `axis` argument is not explicitly specified then the tensor level maximum element is returned (i.e. all axes are reduced).

```
In [58]: tf.reduce_max(x).eval()
Out[58]: 220
```