# Can I mutate a python list inside a tensorflow control loop

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to add tensors to a python list inside a tensorflow control loop.

My code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    c = lambda i, limit: tf.less(i, limit)
    t = (1,5)
    x = []
    def loop_forward(i, limit):
        x.append(1)
        return tf.tuple([i + 1, limit])
    loop = tf.while_loop(c, loop_forward, loop_vars=t, back_prop=False, name="loop")[0]
    with tf.control_dependencies([loop]):
        b = tf.stack(x)

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    print(sess.run(b))
```

This produces `[1]` but not `[1,1,1,1]` as I would expect. Any idea why?

Following David's answer, I tried to do this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    c = lambda i, limit: tf.less(i, limit)
    t = (1,5)
    v = tf.convert_to_tensor([1])
    with tf.control_dependencies([v]):
        def loop_forward(i, limit):
            v = tf.concat([v,tf.convert_to_tensor([1])], axis=0)
            return tf.tuple([i + 1, limit])
        loop = tf.while_loop(c, loop_forward, loop_vars=t, back_prop=False, name="loop")[0]
        with tf.control_dependencies([loop]):
            b = v

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    print(sess.run(b))
```

That seems to produce this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-looping-3.py", line 12, in <module>
    loop = tf.while_loop(c, loop_forward, loop_vars=t, back_prop=False, name="loop")[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2934, in while_loop
    result = loop_context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2720, in BuildLoop
    pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2662, in _BuildLoop
    body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
  File "test-looping-3.py", line 10, in loop_forward
    v = tf.concat([v,tf.convert_to_tensor([1])], axis=0)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'v' referenced before assignment
```

But `v` is not a variable, it is a `Tensor`, so not sure how this error comes.

Comment: @ src, I'm not sure when you edited this question. You should just post issues like that as new questions. SO articles don't lend themselves to long-running threads, it's best to solve one focused problem in each question and open a new question for each new issue you encounter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No python in TF while loops.

You can only use tensorflow constructs within a tensorflow while loop. `x.append(1)` is a python construct.

In fact here's an interesting bit of important trivia regarding TF while loops, `loop_forward` will only be called **once**. That's because it only defines the TF graph operations. Tensorflow will just run those operations multiple times based on your condition `c = lambda i, limit: tf.less(i, limit)`.

With that bit of trivia it should be clear why treating `loop_forward` as a loop in the traditional python sense is erroneous.

You can, however achieve your goal, you just need to use tensorflow constructs to do so. `tf.concat` is probably what you want to use to concatenate a value onto the end of a tensor. Everything's a tensor in Tensorflow.

Comment: I have updated the question, could you please have a look?

Comment: `v` needs to be one of your loop variables. Pass in an empty tensor, then concatenate values onto it, and return the value v in your `loop_forward` function. Tensorflow while loops are a little mind-bending to think about. Basically, you pass in a set of variables, you can do whatever you want to them and then return all of them. By the way, the return doesn't have to be `tf.tuple()`, you can just return the 3 tensors. If you continue to run into issues it's probably best to start a new question rather than extend this one too much further, but feel free to reference it and I'm happy to look.

Comment: Here's a nice example of how to structure a while loop like this, it's actually very similar to what you want to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49314186/tensorflow-how-to-implement-cumulative-maximum/49342079#49342079

Comment: thanks! your last example is very similar to what i want.