# ValueError: Initializer for variable cudnn_gru/opaque_kernel/ is from inside a control-flow construct, such as a loop or conditional

Tags: python, tensorflow

#### System information

- **Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow)**: Yes
- **OS Platform and Distribution**: Ubuntu 16.04
- **TensorFlow installed from**: Binary
- **TensorFlow version**: 1.5.0
- **Python version**: 3.5.2
- **CUDA/cuDNN version**: 9.0/7
- **GPU model and memory**: NVIDIA GTX 1080 8GB x 4
- **Exact command to reproduce**: Code as below

I have been trying to use a for-loop with `tf.cond` applied on `cudnn_gru` to run multiple times on inputs, and the minimum error reproducible code is as below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
max_para = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
num_units = 150
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[15,8,num_units])
class cudnn_gru:
    def __init__(self):
        self.gru_fw = tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnGRU(1, num_units, 
            kernel_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1))
        with tf.variable_scope('CUDNN_GRU', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
            self.init_fw = tf.get_variable("init_fw",shape=[1, 8, num_units],initializer=
                tf.zeros_initializer())
            self.init_bw = tf.get_variable("init_bw",shape=[1, 8, num_units],initializer=
                tf.zeros_initializer())
    def __call__(self,inputs):
        out_fw, _ = self.gru_fw(inputs, initial_state=(self.init_fw,))

class cudnn_gru2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.gru_fw = tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnGRU(1, num_units-1, 
            kernel_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1))
        with tf.variable_scope('CUDNN_GRU', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
            self.init_fw = tf.get_variable("init_fw",shape=[1, 8, num_units],initializer=
                tf.zeros_initializer())
            self.init_bw = tf.get_variable("init_bw",shape=[1, 8, num_units],initializer=
                tf.zeros_initializer())
    def __call__(self,inputs):
        out_fw, _ = self.gru_fw(inputs, initial_state=(self.init_fw,))

def get_output():
    gru = cudnn_gru()
    out = gru(inputs)
    return tf.constant(1)

def get_output2():
    gru = cudnn_gru2()
    out = gru(inputs)
    return tf.constant(2)

for i in range(3):
    i_ = tf.constant(i)
    out = tf.cond(i_<max_para,get_output,get_output2)
```

The error stacktrace is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 41, in <module>
    out = tf.cond(i_<max_para,get_output,get_output2)
  File "/home/search/snetP/virtual_bhavya/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 316, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/search/snetP/virtual_bhavya/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 1894, in cond
    orig_res_t, res_t = context_t.BuildCondBranch(true_fn)
  File "/home/search/snetP/virtual_bhavya/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 1752, in BuildCondBranch
    original_result = fn()
  File "temp.py", line 31, in get_output
    out = gru(inputs)
  File "temp.py", line 15, in __call__
    out_fw, _ = self.gru_fw(inputs, initial_state=(self.init_fw,))
  File "/home/search/snetP/virtual_bhavya/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 636, in __call__
    self.build(input_shapes)
  File "/home/search/snetP/virtual_bhavya/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/cudnn_rnn/python/layers/cudnn_rnn.py", line 357, in build
    "opaque_kernel", initializer=opaque_params_t, validate_shape=False)
  File "/home/search/snetP/virtual_bhavya/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1262, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/search/snetP/virtual_bhavya/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1097, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/search/snetP/virtual_bhavya/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 427, in get_variable
    return custom_getter(**custom_getter_kwargs)
  File "/home/search/snetP/virtual_bhavya/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/cudnn_rnn/python/layers/cudnn_rnn.py", line 290, in _update_trainable_weights
    variable = getter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/search/snetP/virtual_bhavya/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 404, in _true_getter
    use_resource=use_resource, constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/search/snetP/virtual_bhavya/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 806, in _get_single_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/search/snetP/virtual_bhavya/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 229, in __init__
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/search/snetP/virtual_bhavya/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 342, in _init_from_args
    "initializer." % name)
ValueError: Initializer for variable cudnn_gru/opaque_kernel/ is from inside a control-flow construct, such as a loop or conditional. When creating a variable inside a loop or conditional, use a lambda as the initializer.
```

How can I achieve this without causing compilation error during model building?

Answer (score 1):

`tf.cond` and `tf.while` loops work by calling the true/false function or loops condition/body functions only **once**. Those functions return some OP, or group of OPs perform some function such as check a condition and return true/false or in the case of the while body perform some set of actions.

Tensorflow only needs to call your function once to get the definition of the operations it will need. Tensorflow will handle calling that set of operations in a loop or as is necessary.

Notice that this means that the dependency graph is static, nothing is changing while the loop executes. Tensorflow is simply adjusting dependencies and what the next step in the dependency graph is.

So, if you were to create a variable as part of the loop you would be changing the structure of the dependency graph - this isn't how the loops/conditions are designed to be used.

You need to define your variable outside of the condition or loop function. You can access the variable from within the loop function, but not create it there.

Notice in an RNN/GRU that you only have one set of weights that are applied at every time step. So you don't need to be calling `tf.get_variable` inside the condition/while function, you certainly can create the 3 variables you need one time up front.

Also, I expect that the way you defined your function as a class is wrong. Since tensorflow is only every calling that function once the whole class is overkill and probably confusing matters.

Here's an example of a tf while loop that I coded a while back that may give you a good example to follow. I would try to simplify it to follow this example format (e.g. remove the class).

[Tensorflow: How to implement cumulative maximum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49314186/tensorflow-how-to-implement-cumulative-maximum/49342079#49342079)

Comment: I understood what you're trying to say, but can you provide me minor workable example with `tf.cond` and `tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.Cudnn_GRU`? Thanks.

Comment: I created those variables outside the tf.cond scope, and it gives the same error.

Comment: you created those variables outside of the functions returned by the `tf.cond()`? I'd just double check because it might be another error on a different line.  Can you post your new code?